# OPENROWSET syntax when using a variable

Tags: sql, lotus-domino, lotus, openrowset

I am trying to pull data back from a database on a Domino server and if I do not provide a where clause it works great and returns all 229,000 records. However I want it to pull back the 1 record in the WHERE clause, but I can't get it to work.

In the following example I keep getting the error

Incorrect syntax near '38243'.

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Thanks

Graeme

```
 Declare @FNUM varchar(10)
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @FNUM ='''38243-'''
Set @sql = 'SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
''MSDASQL'',
''DSN=Dev-Aban'',
''select * from Therefore where @FNUM='+convert(varchar(10),@FNUM) + ''')'

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: You Can't use variable within OPENROWSET

Comment: Thanks Rajesh.

I have now solved it using OPENQUERY and passing in a variable.

Graeme

Comment: Can you please share the query..?/